# ¿Cómo colocar titulos personalizados en grafica t student de visualize?

Tags: r

tengo esta distribucion t student pero me agrega titulos ya predeterminados como podria hacer para eliminarlos y colocar unos personalizados?, este es el codigo en r studio.

```
install.packages("visualize")
library(visualize)
visualize.t(stat = c(-1.96, 1.96), df = 3430.8, section = "tails") 
abline(v = 1.5, col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 2) 
text(1.7, 0.2, expression(t[1.1584]), col = "red") 
text(2.5, 0.05,  expression(1.96), col = "blue") 
text(-2.5, 0.05, expression(-1.96), col = "blue") 
text(0, 0.2, expression(0.95), col = "black")
```

Adjunto la imagen de que es lo que me da quisiera eliminar esos titulos y agregar otros. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de ajustar este dato en el gráfico, no hay ningún parámetro ni ninguna función para hacerlo. Lo único que eventualmente podrías hacer, es modificar el paquete:

1. Clonar localmente el [proyecto](https://github.com/coatless/visualize)
2. Modificar los títulos de cada distribución definidos [aquí](https://github.com/coatless/visualize/blob/master/data-raw/visualize.distributions.R)
3. Modificar eventualmente la función [`visualize_contious()`](https://github.com/coatless/visualize/blob/master/R/visualize.continuous.R)
4. Construir nuevamente el paquete y usar tu versión local.